# How to write transfer function is s-plane of single bridge rectifier?

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function, simulink

I am trying to write a transfer function of single phase rectifier so I can use in Matlab to look for phase margin and gain margin:
here an example I took from Circuit-lab
[image]

I could write the transfer function in positve sinewave and negative sinewave but together I am not sure how to proceed.

Circuit during positive sine wave:
[image]

Circuit during negative sine wave:

[image]

I am bit skeptical if this method is correct ?

Comment: Transfer function defined for linear systems

Comment: Understood. so if you use it during positive sinewave, would that make sense?

Comment: This can help with a little simplification ... https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19930013827/downloads/19930013827.pdf

Comment: Ans-No, "During positive sinewave " but what would you assume for negative cycle (because for Laplace you have to define input function for $$t\in(0,\infty)$$ ?

Comment: @user215805 the input function is defined as you mention for t>0 but how can I not ignore the effect of the negative sinewave when I write my transfer function in only positive sinewave whic is half

Comment: Ok, can you show your transfer function (either by writing here or by an image of your solution) with assumptions as you mentioned? , if you are interested to know what's wrong with this approach, I'll try to help you!

Comment: Sorry for the very late answer. here is my equations:during charging: Vout/Vin=(RL)/(RL+Rsc+s*Rsc*RL*C).
-during discharge=Vout/Vdc=(RL*C)/(RL*C*s+1)

Answer (score 2):

Diodes are non linear, you can write something using the diode eqn, I = Is*(e^(V/Vt) -1) or words to that effect, but that is a time domain thing, frequency domain, that non linearity is going to bite you hard.

$$Id = Is * (e^(Vd/Vt) -1)$$
$$Vd = Vin - Vout - Id * Rsrc$$
$$Vout = \int{(Id - Vout/RLoad)\delta t}$$

Substitute....
It's been years, and your mathematics atrophies annoyingly quickly.

Comment: I am looking how to write the diode voltage ins-plane but seems tricky as you said

Answer (score 0):

Well, notice that when using an ideal diode we get (when the sine-wave input \$\text{V}_\text{in}\left(t\right)=\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\sin\left(\omega t\right)\$ is positive and below it's maximum: \$0\le t\le\frac{\pi}{2\omega}\$):

$$\text{V}_{1|\text{out}}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\text{||}\text{R}_\text{load}}{\text{R}_\text{s}+\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\text{||}\text{R}_\text{load}\right)}\cdot\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

After the maximum (\$\frac{\pi}{2\omega}\le t\le\frac{5\pi}{2\omega}\$) until the next the discharge function of the capacitor hits the next sign-wave (this is between \$\frac{\pi}{2\omega}< t<\frac{5\pi}{2\omega}\$):

$$\text{V}_{2|\text{out}}\left(t\right)=\hat{\text{V}}_{1|\text{out}}\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{CR}_\text{load}}\right)\tag2$$

And after this, the cycle repeats.

Comment: the second one is critical during the negative sinewave. now, if I want to include the transfer function of positive sinewve of the V1!out in another system with other transfer function, i will miss the negative sinewave?

Comment: @Yaakov No that is not true. The capacitor will discharge when the input will reach it's maximum, not when the input crosses \$t=0\$.

Comment: you are right, the capacity discharge when there input sine wave reaches the peak. my question is if I use only the positive transfer function with other blocks like to find out the  global transfer function of the whole system will lead me to wrong results

Comment: like I call G1=V1out/Vin(positive sinewave), then for example; Gglobal=G1*G2*G3